# cannot include a user module in electron (node js)

Tags: node.js, electron

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9gA5.png)

[importing the user module connection.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRtE6.png)

[connection.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbq71.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU3zW.png)

This app is based on electron everything is working fine apart from the fact that I cannot require a self created module. It is working fine in the same file just cannot require it externally. I think the renderer somehow cannot find the module.

I have tried setting app to var app = electron.app
and, i have also tried remote but that was a bit defying logic however, it didn't work seriously fed up!!!!!!

Comment: Could you please add the related code to your question? It's easier to understand to problem and help you.

Comment: I have added all the snapshots already. Found a solution by using 'electron-require' package however, i am very interested in knowing the generic way of doing it .... Any suggestions,  the aim is to include user created module in electron however my renderer was unable to locate the modules unless i used electron-require but there must be a generic way

Comment: add your self-answer @Xeonray?